# how to make the flex item always fill the remaining space of the flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to HTML, CSS, and trying make the  fill the remaining space of it's container.
The problem is when the content of  is too long, it will exceed out of the container, which make the `break-word` not work (I think so)
This is my codes:

```css
.a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}
.b {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
}
.c {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: blue;
  height: 20px; 
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">vcvxzc</div>
  <div class="c">
    <span>      ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
    </span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

When the span is not too long:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmaib.png)

When it's too long:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V3jZ.png)

how can I make it always contain inside the flex container.
thank you so much

Comment: min-width: 0 to `.c` and `.c span`

Answer (score 0):

if you need to keep height on 20px you can use the style bellow to hide rest of text

```
.c {
    overflow-y: hidden;
   }
```

but if height is not important for you and you just want to break the text in that width you can use this style:

```
.c {
    background-color: gray;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    word-break: break-word;
   }
```

Comment: Yes the height is unimportant so I want to go another way is too display `block`. and after I set the min-width:0px, it worked, do you know why. Thank you for your help

Comment: Your welcome. yes, that's another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need..

All you need to do is, change `word-wrap: break-word` to `word-break: break-word` and adjust height appropriately

```css
.a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}
.b {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
}
.c {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: blue;
  height: auto; 
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">vcvxzc</div>
  <div class="c">
    <span>      ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
    </span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear enough.
In the title you asked for how to fill the entire container of a flex parent. You can do so by using `Flex-Grow`

In the description you asked for how can you prevent overflow in a flex container, you can do so by `Flex-wrap`.

```css
.a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.b {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
}
.c {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: blue;
  height: 20px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  /* hidden Or scroll */
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">vcvxzc</div>
  <div class="c">
    <span>      ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
    </span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confuse, I acctually just want the second child to be always in the flex container, auto word break when it content is too long. This is my code now

Answer (score -1):

try this css:

```
.c span{
  word-break: break-all;
}
```